# Show / hide DIV when scroll page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show the "hide_show" section when I scroll down and the "three" section appears on the screen. I want to hide the "hide_show" section when I scroll up and the "three" section disappears from the screen. I want to use JS with "fade in / face out" effect. Please help

```css
.hide_show {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#two {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#three {
  background-color: red;
}

#four {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <section class="hide_show">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          one
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="two">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          two
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="three">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          three
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="four">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          four
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/czyjg2tu/1/

Comment: `Element.onscroll = function(){ if(this.scrollTop === 100){ /* set your css class here - animate using CSS */ }`

Comment: I want to show the "show_hide" section when I scroll to the "three" section. Not 100 px from the top. If you can, paste the code on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit difficult to fully understand the question, but this should hopefully get you started.

Let me know if you have any other questions on what each part of this does.

```js
let three = document.querySelector('#three')
let hideShow = document.querySelectorAll('.hide_show')

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  // If the user has scrolled to the three section
  if (window.pageYOffset >= three.offsetTop) {
    hideShow.forEach((item) => {
      item.style.display = 'block'
    })
    
  // If the user has not reached the three section
  } else {
    hideShow.forEach((item) => {
      item.style.display = 'none'
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.hide_show {
  /* Force the hideShow section to always be at the top */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#two {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#three {
  background-color: red;
}

#four {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <section class="hide_show">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          one
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="two">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          two
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="three">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          three
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="four">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          four
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Chase, I want to change more parameters (not just "margin-top"). I want to change 'display' (from 'none' to 'block '). How can I add this to your code?